# MySQL inner join on same table

Tags: mysql

I have the following database schema: http://pastebin.com/tET8Wj17

I would like to make a query, getting all the message when my user_id is equal to the receiver or sender_id, but also takes and fetch id_parent message.

I thought about using INNER JOIN, but can't really get this to work with the same table.

Comment: Use sqlfiddle instead of pastebin - much friendlier for this kind of thing.

Comment: Here it is in SQLfiddle (there is no ability to do constraints in SQLfiddle as far as I can see): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can INNER JOIN on the same table - you just need to give each table a distinct alias.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table1 as t2 ON t1.someField = t2.someField
```

Reflexive joins like this can cause performance issues - be careful and make sure you are able to keep your application performant.

Answer (score 2):

A self join is simple enough using an alias

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
ON a.id = b.parent_id
```